# How to plot real time sensor values in Graph in android?

Tags: android, graph, plot, real-time, android-sensors

I want to plot the graph of sensors value in android app.

Which library will be perfect for this ?

Answer (score 15):

There are a few different graphing libraries available for Android.

For my own app, I'm currently live-plotting sensor data using [Android GraphView](http://www.android-graphview.org/).  It runs smoothly, and is quite customizable.  The screenshots on the site look basic, but you can change it to fit your design.

I'm probably going to start using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) soon as well.  It looks very good and is quite customizable, but I'm not sure if it supports live graphing like GraphView does.

Here's a list of other Android graphing libraries I found on Google: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/40

<s>UPDATE: MPAndroidChart does support live graphing. I've moved to that, and would recommend it. It has good docs for newcomers.</s>

UPDATE 2: MPAndroidChart does NOT support live graphing according to the [official page](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/dynamic-realtime-data/):

> MPAndroidChart is free software, as a result dynamic & realtime data is not officially supported.

Comment: MPAndroidChart doesn't support live data, you must have to save live data to array before